# Have to focus input box twice so on keyup listener works IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an input box that takes SSN and when inputs value length reach 10 it is suppose to skip the if and do a ajax call. It works fine in all borwsers except IE 9.

There is nothing wrong with the ajax call and it all works fine if I start by focusing the input, blurring it and focus again before i type in it

I've been spending hours trying to figure this out and tried everything i could think of so any help would be welcome.

Thanks

Here is the input, the input binding and then the function it calls on keydown

```
<input class="paymentInput required" id="payerSsn" type="text" placeholder="Kennitala greiðanda" maxlength="10"/>

$("#payerSsn").on('input keyup change', function () {
    GetCustomerInfoFromSsn($(this).val(), 'payer');
});



function GetCustomerInfoFromSsn(ssn, type) {
if (ssn.length < 10) {
    $("#" + type + "Ssn").removeClass("done");
    $(".paymentInput.autoFill." + type).val("").removeClass("done");
    return;
}

if (store.vefur)
    $(".paymentInputLoader.nameInput").show();
else
    $(".paymentInputLoader").show();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urlPreFix + config.url.customerInfoFormSsn + ssn,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: config.constant.webServiceTimeOut,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (custInfo) {
        if (custInfo.length > 0) {
            $("#notValidSsn").hide();
            ProcessPaymentCustInfo(custInfo, type);
        }
        else if (custInfo.name == null) {
            $(".paymentInputLoader").hide();
            $("#payerSsn").addClass("error");
            $("#notValidSsn").fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $("#notValidSsn").hide();
            ProcessPaymentCustInfo(custInfo, type);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $(".paymentInputLoader").hide();
        $("#" + type + "Name").prop("disabled", "");
        $("#" + type + "Name").focus();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: FYI: `.prop("disabled", "");` should be `.prop("disabled", false);` i guess

Comment: The only problem I see is IE9. Try using $("#payerSsn").focus() when the user focuses the text box and see if that works.

Comment: What is the value of `ssn.length` in IE9 when you expect it to be 10?

Comment: A. Wolff - When i console logged it it dose not log, like the code never reaches the GetCustomerInfoFromSsn function if I don't focus the input twice.

Sheng Slogar - It's not working.

Comment: And if i debug it in the developers tool it works fine! Not other wise